# ruby nl2br outside <code> ... </code>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, replace, tags

I've been struggling on this thing for a week without being able to find what I'm looking for.

Here is what I'd like to do:

I'm setting up a wiki where I can post all my knowledge to (yes, I know a couple things :p) but I can't render it the way I'd like to.
The bodies of my posts are text fields. In order to render them the right way I run the following command:

```
@post.body.gsub("\n", "<br />")
```

I also have some tags with some code inside that looks like this < code> my code < /code>.

Here come's the issue. Every line between the < code> and < /code> tags are changed to 
 but it doesn'r render properly since I'm using a code render template.

Therefore, I'd like to know if there is a way to change all \n to < br /> except for those between < code> and < /code>

Thank you everyone for reading this and helping me out.

PS: Please do not consider the spaces after the < in each tag. I had to do this to "espace" them.

Julien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`simple_format` will replace your `\n` to `<br/>` and double `\n\n` to `<p></p>`
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format

And here is a helper method for your problem

```
def text_format(text)
  reg = /(<code>[.|\W|\w]+<\/code>)/
  text.split(reg).map{|t| t =~ reg ? t : t.gsub(/\n/, "<br />") }.join()
end

text = 'Hello pedro!

        Here is my code:

        <code>
          def text_format(text)
            reg = /(<code>[.|\W|\w]+<\/code>)/
            text.split(reg).map{|t| t =~ reg ? t : t.gsub(/\n/, "<br />") }.join()
          end
        </code>

        Good luck!'

text_format text
#=> "Hello pedro!<br /><br />Here is my code:<br /><br /><code>\n  def text_format(text)\n    reg = /(<code>[.|\\W|\\w]+<\\/code>)/\n    text.split(reg).map{|t| t =~ reg ? t.gsub(/\\n/, "<br />") : t }.join()\n  end\n</code><br /><br />Good luck!"
```

Comment: Okay,
this helper is nice but it's actually not solving my problem since it's inserting br> tags between <code> and </code> and rendering my code snippets with br> tags in front of each line.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Amazing,
it's working like a charm.

I just need to understand the whole code now :-)